# How to create a dynamic variable that show the actual value?

Tags: javascript, html

i've created a JavaScript Code that is doing what i want but it doesn't keep the "var" actual.

It should change the float of `<nav>` when the `<header>`'s height is greater than 51px. But it doesnt take anny effect when you resize the window. It works when i "refresh" the page, it should change the "float" "on the fly". That means when someone shrinks the window it should change and not when you refresh the page.

```
    var clientHeight = document.getElementById('header').clientHeight;
if (clientHeight < 51) {
 document.getElementById('nav').style.float = "right";
}
else {
 document.getElementById('nav').style.float = "left";
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DamianToczek/4zkofskb/)

Comment: Please include all relevant code right here on StackOverflow.

Comment: i've added some codes, i don't know what all is needed. But basicly <li> is a part from my navigation, <main> is where it should be loaded + js file. I guess its all there what could be relevant.

Comment: It is better to include too much, than to include too little. Anyway, I hope someone can help you.

Comment: Someone.. nice.. so you came only to tell me i need to add some code.. cool i was thinkink i get some help because this website is known for help

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that the jsfiddle using HTTPS and your link is using HTTP, the browser will block this request since it's not secure:

[image]

If you have HTTPS on your website instead of putting http://damina... put //damina (without https or http then the browser will load the iframe according to the main website) or https://damina

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have it as <a href="home.php"> not as <a href="https://damiantoczek.de/home.php">

Comment: try this javascript code: $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#main-content").load("home.php");
});

$('a').on('click', function(){
 var page = $(this).attr('href');
 $("#main-content").load(page);
 return false;
});

Comment: Now it works like this, basicly it doensn't work. Look http://damiantoczek.de klick on the bright button on right side.

Comment: It opens but new page, not in the <div>.